# retrieve a paginated set of sorted results from a mongoDB array

Tags: mongodb

I need to be able to run a query on an array that contains all my chat messages with an "updated_at" time stamp. I do not want to retrieve all the results and load them into memory as this would be a huge load over time. I want to access the array, sort it by ascending date and then get the first block of 10.

$chatroomConversation = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection($chatroomCollection)
            ->orderBy('messages.updated_at', 'asc');

I am of course getting just one result which is the parent document.

Comment: You sure your chats will never exceed 16MB? There is a 16MB document size limit. So storing chats in an array is probably not what you want, the first place

Comment: You are right, i decided to rebuild the database for this exact same reason and it was ugly. Having one document for each message was perfect and how i should have done it in the beginning considering i have a collection for each chatroom. It was a design flaw on my part. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: You do not need a collection for each chat room. Actually, your chat room names could make a nice shard key. Will write an answer up tomorrow.

Comment: Ok i'd love to read it but if you want to see what i did it's pretty amazing and extremely scalable as everything is contained in its own collection.

Comment: Yes, please provide example data ;)

Comment: PM me. My profile should have my contact info.

Comment: Except it does not ;) and it does not make sense either to exchange that in private, either. This site is about public exchange of knowledge ;)

Comment: I agree. I just figured most people wouldn't care or would consider it off topic.

Comment: Done brother. Please upvote or something, i never earned anything on this site :)

Answer (score 1):

SO this is what i did instead:

code to create a collection on the fly:

```
     public function newCollection ($collectionName) {        
        if (config('settings.DebugTraceLevelFunctions') == true) { Log::channel('merlin_debug')->info('newCollection function in CreateCustomCollections.php'); }

        Schema::connection('mongodb')->create($collectionName, function ($collection) {
           $collection->string('UID');
        });

    }
```

How to use this class:

```
        $chatroomCollectionName = 'chatroom_'.$newChatroomData['UID'];

        $newCustomCollection = new CreateCustomCollections();
        $newCustomCollection->newCollection($chatroomCollectionName);
```

and this is how you retrieve the data:

```
        //generate the collection name to retrieve it
        $chatroomCollection = 'chatroom_' . $chatroomUID;

        //connect to the database and insert the new message
        $chatroomConversation = DB::connection('mongodb')
            ->collection($chatroomCollection)
            ->insert([
                'UID' => (string)$varUID,
                'member' => $newMessage['member'],
                'message' => $newMessage['message'],
                'status' => $newMessage['status'],
                'created_at' => $timeStamp,
                'updated_at' => $timeStamp,
            ]);
```